# Google sign I didSignInFor. I am getting ID Token expired

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, google-signin

I using google with sign in. From today morning, google sign in was not working. Not sure why its happening. I am getting error :

```
ID Token expired
```

On my console error. Any one please help me why its happening. I am new to it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleSignInBtn: UIButton! 

 @IBAction func GoogleLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
 if (error == nil) {
} else {
 print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}
}
```

My system time and date is correct only. Even the token is correct only. Android is working fine. But in iOS its getting this issues. Should i need to do pod install again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change your device's date and time to set it automatically. Your device must have the correct date and time otherwise Google will throw "ID Token expired" error.

Comment: Thank u so much. It's my mistake. Setting correct time is resolved my problem with: Code=-15 "ID Token expired"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same return with Error "ID Token expired"

I made a lot of research and tests, so here is result:

- At first, I found out that the error was only on one device. Other devices with this gmail didn't give that error
- Secondly, I checked what is the difference between them
- On this "bug"-device gmail was using long time ago or was singed out, but credentials was saved anyway.

**Solution**:
You or your users have to sign in into gmail again. You can do it in Gmail app.

It helped for me and I hope it will help for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Add GoogleService-Info.plist file to your project root folder

write your clientId in didfinishLaunch:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = "***********.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

Go to project -> Info -> URL Types and add URL Scheme from googleService-Info.plist in this format:

```
com.googleusercontent.apps.***************
```

Add following code in button action:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate=self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

Add extension to your ViewController:

```
extension ViewController: GIDSignInDelegate
{
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)
{
    if error == nil
    {
        let image: URL = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 70)!
        let imageString:String = image.absoluteString
        
        socialData(social_id: user.userID ?? "", email: 

user.profile.email ?? "", name: user.profile.name ?? "", image: imageString, type: 2)
        }
        else
        {
            print(error)
            self.SocialDataDelegate?.returnSocial()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Few steps where already i did. Now i put the .plist file to the root folder of the project. Still i am getting ID `Token expired`

Comment: I think its date & time related issue. Please set your current date & time & check.

Comment: Yes icoderz-developers is right reset your reset to your time zone